# Defeating spam registrations

Tags: javascript, forms, captcha, spam

I am trying to learn as much as possible about running a high-profile website. I designing some user registration screens and was thinking about the typical CAPTCHA, or annoying alternatives. In my opinion, having them either causes accessibility issues, or simply bothers potential customers and inhibits their registration process.

My question is whether spambots recognize and trigger JavaScript events, such as the `keydown` or `keypress` event on an input field. From what I can gather, most bots simply do form posts via the action attribute and don't programmatically "fill out" web forms.

In theory, I could add JavaScript that something like the following:

```
<input name="email" />
<input name="human" type="hidden" />
<script>
var emailField = document.getElementById( 'email' );
emailField.onkeydown = function( ) {
   document.getElementById( 'human' ).value = "human";
};
</script>
```

Then, on the server side, I could verify that the post data includes a value of "human" for the hidden form field.

Is this a viable solution, at least as effective as typing in a bunch of random, difficult-to-read characters?  Would using a random generated value from the server be more helpful in repetitive attempts than a static value of "human"?

Comment: what about plugins that autofill out forms for real users?

Comment: If someone is determined, they'll figure out what your JS is doing and automate it. So while this might thwart a generic spambot, it won't stop someone who really wants to spam your site.

Comment: @MattPileggi, good point as I had forgotten about autocompleted fields.

Comment: @Barmar, I understand I cannot completely prevent a determined individual, as even the crappy text-CAPTCHA's can be circumvented. I was just seeing if this would be at least as effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Most** spam bots will simply look for a `<form>` on your page and then post data directly to the URL specified in the `action` attribute.  This is very simple, lightweight, and easy to do.

**Some** spam bots will actually use a headless browser (such as PhantomJS) which executes JavaScript on the page.  These spam bots are much harder to fool, but few bots use this method since it is much more expensive (in CPU and RAM).

I've found that it's generally fine to go for blocking the most common spam bots through a honeypot (field on the page that is removed programmatically, and other similar methods).  Some bots will get through, and anyone who does manual analysis to find a way to exploit your page will still get in.  For most sites, this is good enough, and provides a good balance in preventing spam while keeping your site usable.

Comment: +1 "anyone who does manual analysis to find a way to exploit your page will still get in"

Comment: I think I will work with the honeypot method, as I had researched it prior to posting this question, and just thought the key press detection would be a clever alternative to unnecessary semantics. It seems that, in conjunction with a time-check, the honeypot may provide the best balance between effectiveness and user annoyance.