# Basic protection of PHP scripts

Tags: php

I'm in the process of learning more PHP. I've not really done any PHP before, only enough for basic emailing on contact forms. In the past when I've made such forms I've occasionally had spam emails come through via that script. From the frequency of the emails and the content it is very much apparent that it isn't someone coming on the website and spamming via the form but rather they know the url of the php file and are submitting data to it via that in some way; what is the best way to prevent this sort of thing happening.

Comment: [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)!?

Comment: Read about `csrf protection` also [read this](http://devgrow.com/simple-php-honey-pot/) (You can use hidden fields as a honey trap to identify bots)

Comment: use captcha but it's sometimes annoys the user so better use Csrf token to prevent csrf (Cross Site Foreign Request)

Comment: In addition to the above maybe a hidden trap form field as shown [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-spam-prevention-using-hidden-form-fields/).

Comment: See also:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/22307978/362536

Comment: captcha is the best to prevent them

Answer (score 2):

If you're in your very early stages of PHP (or programming in general) I would recommend that you create an input in your form which you hide or move off screen using css.

This would mean that no real user would fill this, but when when a bots comes to your page and submit the form, they would fill it in with some garbage data.

In your php code handling the submission, simply check to see if this field has been submitted or not. If it has then you know it was not a real person, so discard the submission and do not proceed further with sending the email.

Note: I'm only recommending the approach above for learning purposes and for tiny projects that are not really in production use. If you need a more robust solution, then look into some sort of capcha solution or some javascript that adds some csrf type of checks to your form.